# No viable conversion from '__wrap_iter<std::__1::vector<MenuItem *>::const_pointer>' to '__wrap_iter<std::__1::vector<MenuItem>::pointer>'

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator, constants

I am working on a file that I have to iterate through the object's vector but for some reason I am getting this error:

```
No viable conversion from '__wrap_iter<std::__1::vector<MenuItem *>::const_pointer>' to '__wrap_iter<std::__1::vector<MenuItem>::pointer>'
```

this is the line which causes the error:

```
for (vector<MenuItem>::iterator p = m->menuItems()->begin() ; p != m->menuItems()->end(); p++) {
```

the class function which I am trying to iterate through:

```
 virtual const vector<MenuItem*>* menuItems() const = 0;
```

** the virtual function at the derived classes are:

```
virtual const vector<MenuItem*>* menuItems() const { return nullptr; }

virtual const vector<MenuItem*>* menuItems() const { return &m_menuItems; }
```

Edit:

After finding what I wanted to find with the iterator, I want to recall this function (recursive call) with the newfound item. however, when I am trying to do so, I am not matching the function call.
the function call is :

```
 void listAll(const MenuItem* m)
```

the way I

```
for (vector<MenuItem*>::const_iterator p = m->menuItems()->begin() ; p != m->menuItems()->end(); p++) {
    cout << (*p)->name();
    if ((*p)->menuItems() == nullptr) {
        cout << endl;
    }
    if ((*p)->menuItems() != nullptr) {
        cout << endl;
        vector<MenuItem*>::const_iterator k = (*p)->menuItems()->begin();
        MenuItem* mPtr = *k;
        listAll(mPtr);
```

Comment: `vector<MenuItem*>::iterator p`

Comment: Does not work as well, this is the error I am getting after adding the "*":
No viable conversion from '__wrap_iter<std::__1::vector<MenuItem *>::const_pointer>' to '__wrap_iter<std::__1::vector<MenuItem *>::pointer>'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here. First, a function with the signature

```
const vector<MenuItem*>* menuItems() const;
```

(virtual or not) returns a pointer to a `const`-qualified instance of a vector. The `begin()` and `end()` member functions of `const`-qualfied vectors return `const_iterator`s, not `iterator`s. As it makes sense that you can't convert a `const_iterator` into an `iterator`, this is an issue.

Second, you are missing an asterisk in the type of the iterator. So the correct type specifier should be

```
vector<MenuItem*>::const_iterator p = m->menuItems()->begin(); ...
//             ^   ^^^^^^
```

Using `auto` type deduction for iterator types is a common pattern, so you could also do

```
for (auto p = m->menuItems()->begin() ; p != m->menuItems()->end(); p++)
    { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Even better: `for (auto item : *m->menuItems())` (or even `MenuItem * item` if style guide says no auto)